# EC2 AMI instances shared password management

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

My goal is to launch 200 instance of windows node of the same ami in aws. These node come up and connect to my head node. Now, every launch of a new node create a new password for that node. This is hard to manage specially if I want to do group remote maitenance.

I was thinking, maybe I can make all of specific ami to have the same password but do I do that ? Should I modify sysprep condfig file C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\sysprep2008.xml or should I disable both set password for the ec2 config tool and then create a AMI?

If the config file, what exactly should I put in the sysprep2008.xml file?

Comment: What do you mean each node launch creates a new password?  You mean for SSH access?  Are you not using keyed access?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the nodes are windows node. Every time a new instance of the AMI is created, the remote desktop/admin password is set to a random number.